# How to do: Reports with concatenated text in fields organized by a key

Tags: ms-access, report, concatenation

I'm trying to create a report in MS Access that has the following form:

[image]

The sample created here would be populated by the following table:

[image]

The column 'FK' refers to a key from another table from which I would populate the title text.  The SysID column contains ids for system text that I would populate into each of the cells.

My limited understanding is that I need to use subreports within a main report.  The subreports would pull the key from 'FK' and use that to select the 'SysID' entries that match the corresponding type for the cell, i.e., Type 1, Type 2, etc.  The text in each cell would be a concatenation of the text for the matching entries found.

Any sample code or links to prior related answers would be extremely appreciated.  I'm pretty lost as to how to get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: How many possible type values? You show only 4.

Comment: Hi @June7, it's only 4 values.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require VBA code. One commonly used function provided by Allen Browne at http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Assuming there is a Titles table where the ID is unique primary key associated with FK in sample table - use that table as source for query then call the function 4 times (also assuming there are only 4 types).

```
SELECT TitleID, "Title_" & TitleID AS Title, 
ConcatRelated("'Sys_' & [sysID]", "sampleTable", "FK=" & [TitleID] & " AND Type=1", "sysID") AS Type1, 
ConcatRelated("'Sys_' & [sysID]", "sampleTable", "FK=" & [TitleID] & " AND Type=2", "sysID") AS Type2,
ConcatRelated("'Sys_' & [sysID]", "sampleTable", "FK=" & [TitleID] & " AND Type=3", "sysID") AS Type3,
ConcatRelated("'Sys_' & [sysID]", "sampleTable", "FK=" & [TitleID] & " AND Type=4", "sysID") AS Type4
FROM Titles;
```

Alternative is CROSSTAB (again assuming only 4 types):

```
TRANSFORM Max(ConcatRelated("'Sys_' & [sysID]","sampleTable","FK=" & [FK] & " AND Type=" & [Type], "sysID")) AS SysType
SELECT [FK], "Title_" & [FK] AS Title
FROM sampleTable
GROUP BY [FK], "Title_" & [FK] 
PIVOT [Type] IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Be aware performance can be slow with large dataset. Both appear to have same performance with sample data.

No subreports needed. However, building a stable report based on CROSSTAB where columns returned are dynamic can be a challenge.

Comment: Thanks so much @June7.  This really helps me out.  I should have been clearer but the numbers under the 'sysID' column are actually keys referencing a 'Systems' table which has the corresponding 'sysID' keys and the respective titles.  I was hoping to pull those titles from the Systems table.  I've looked at ConcatRelated but it doesn't seem clear that this is possible.  Do you know if this might be doable?  Thanks!

Comment: Allen Browne code would require you to build a query that joins sampleTable to the Systems table and use that query as source for the function. I have seen other code that allows passing an SQL statement instead of table or query name to the function but finding it again would be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with June7 that no subreports are needed. If one of the two vectors (FK or Type) are fairly static, no crosstab is needed either. What is needed however is a so-called String aggregation function, used in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause (which is really all crosstabs are, dynamic GROUP BY queries). Two caveats:
- Custom functions are ALWAYS slow. Think several seconds for a couple thousand records, up to minutes or even hours for tens of thousands or millions. Your task will be to reduce the actual data being processed to an absolute minimum and JOIN any additional data needed 
- Custom aggregate functions are SLOWER. :)
You will find an excellent custom Access string aggregate function at this link:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2380/Domain-Aggregate-for-Concatenating-Values-by-Group-in-Microsoft-Access.html
This is another stack exchange question talking about your topic:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98089/how-to-get-the-equivalent-of-array-or-string-group-by-aggregate-functions-in-acc

One distinctly possible option is to externalize your data on a SQL server 2017 platform, which comes with an aggregate function called STRING_AGG which you use just as you would SUM or AVG or COUNT. The only question becomes whether you do a crosstab (if neither your FK nor your Type are particularly static) or a handwritten GROUP BY query, which would be much faster. The ideal solution depends thus on the shape and scope of your data. More scope, try for the handwritten solution if one of your two vectors is static enough. Otherwise go for a crosstab.

Another possibility is to do the same thing with PostgresQL, which is open source (free).

I'm happy to produce the query you need if you send a copy of your table that is representative in terms of scope and shape. I'm also happy to show you how to externalize a data source in Access if you don't already know how.

Comment: thanks so much for the offer and the comment!  Sorry to get back to you so late but, if it still stands I may take you up on it.